# How do I send emails to multiple people on outlook in python?

Tags: python, email, outlook

Stuck in a small problem for 2 days. I am trying to send multiple emails using my outlook to multiple people. Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Break an excel file into multiple files basis company names
2. Attach that excel on an email and send. The email is getting picked from a master list of email ids stored in an excel.

**Problem:** 
I am getting the below error code while running the program. I am able to break the large excel into multiple smaller ones, but only the first excel gets mailed and then I get this error message.

(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The item has been moved or deleted.', None, 0, -2147221238), None)

```
#code

import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)


file_path = r'C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Email\Email.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = 'Master excel')
df2 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = 'Email list')

df11 = df1['Co name'].unique()
list_carrier = list(df11)

path = r'C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Python\Email\np\\'
for i in list_carrier:
    dfa = df1[df1['Co Name']==i]
    wb = Workbook()
    path_1=path+i+".xlsx"
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_1, engine='openpyxl', mode='W')
    writer.wb = wb
    dfa.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet1")
    writer.save()

for i in list_carrier:

    email = df2.loc[df2['Co Name'] == i, 'Email'].item()
    mail.cc = 'abc@gmail.com; xyz@gmail.com'
    mail.To = email
    mail.Subject = f" {i} - File for testing"
    mail.Body = """\
    Hi, 

    sending test mail.

    Regards, """

    path_1=path+i+".xlsx"
    mail.Attachments.Add(path_1)
    mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new `MailItem` in the loop after calling the `Send` each time. You cannot submit items more than once, i.e. call the `Send` method twice.

```
#code

import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')


file_path = r'C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Email\Email.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = 'Master excel')
df2 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = 'Email list')

df11 = df1['Co name'].unique()
list_carrier = list(df11)

path = r'C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Python\Email\np\\'
for i in list_carrier:
    dfa = df1[df1['Co Name']==i]
    wb = Workbook()
    path_1=path+i+".xlsx"
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_1, engine='openpyxl', mode='W')
    writer.wb = wb
    dfa.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet1")
    writer.save()

for i in list_carrier:

    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    email = df2.loc[df2['Co Name'] == i, 'Email'].item()
    mail.cc = 'abc@gmail.com; xyz@gmail.com'
    mail.To = email
    mail.Subject = f" {i} - File for testing"
    mail.Body = """\
    Hi, 

    sending test mail.

    Regards, """

    path_1=path+i+".xlsx"
    mail.Attachments.Add(path_1)
    mail.Send()
```